# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object in MVC4 in StoredProcedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i am getting an error `[System.InvalidOperationException] = {"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."}`

i am getting a list of values contining DataType `OracleCLOB` by executing a `StoredProcedure`

here is my code

```
try
        {
            string connectionStrings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnection"].ConnectionString;
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionStrings);
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "Pkg_RTMI_WEB.PRC_GET_RTMI_SIGNATURE";
            command.Parameters.Add("P_MASAG", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction =
                System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            command.Parameters["P_MASAG"].Value = MASAGR_ID;

            command.Parameters.Add("P_SIG", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            OracleDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            con.Close();
            OracleClob clob = null;
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                clob = dr.GetOracleClob(0);
            }
            return clob;

        }
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            /// Exception Block
            BaseObject.IsSuccessful = false;
            BaseObject.Message = "[RTMISignature]: " + ex.Message;

            return null;
        }
```

got error in this line `OracleDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();`

also added  this line to `Web.Config`

```
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="15000" />
</appSettings>
```

but same results
**Note**: `CLOB` contains more than 12k characters

Comment: Add `command.Connection = con;`

Comment: Good, but you really should consider `using` statements for both the connection and datareader